# Accessing attachments in html email?

Tags: html, email, font-face, email-attachments

I'm trying to send a HTML email and it works perfectly fine even the css, but I'm trying to use @font face. If I would be making a normal website I would just have it in a folder on the server. But since there is nothing like that while sending an html email I was wondering whether I could send the font as an attachment and have the html access it. The only thing is that I don't know what the url of email attachments is.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In order to refer to an attachment part from other parts of the message, you need to add a unique [`Content-ID`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-7) header field to the attachment—for example, based on a hash sum of the font file (replace `example.com` with your own domain):

```
Content-ID: <font-d404d13b4009ec52325bafd11e8fa5c2@example.com>
```

Then, use a [`cid:` scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392) URL to refer to this attachment:

```
cid:font-d404d13b4009ec52325bafd11e8fa5c2@example.com
```

This works for images; I highly doubt that it will work for fonts, but you can try.